# Weird behavior in eclipse when editing clojure files

Tags: eclipse, clojure, counterclockwise

I am trying to learn clojure and i installed the counterclockwise plugin in eclipse.

Now when i hover with my mouse over strings containing whitespace or only dots i get this weird menu popup.

[image]

It is really annoying and i have no idea where it is coming from.
If anyone knows how to turn this off i would really appreciate it.